# My script don't upload files with whitespaces but with underscores

Tags: php, file-upload

**When i upload a file with a space, it appear with an underscore but i want to allow whitespaces.
Maybe the solution is in this code:**

```
$_CONFIG['check_file_name_regex'] = '^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\.]+[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]$';
```

**How to allowa whitespaces in my script?**

Comment: White space in file names is generally regarded as a bad idea for compatibility reasons. In this day and age this is really completely baseless, but convention dictates that one wouldn't do this and really there is no reason to - it will potentially cause you problems when addressing stuff through the shell. Hell, some people still name everything in 8 dot 3, as if they still have to support Windows 3.

Comment: Why would you allow whitespaces for a file you upload? Just curious, but I suspect you're going to run into a lot of trouble if you do.

Comment: There are people who name files with spaces, so allowing such files to be uploaded is reasonable, and process them carefully. Wrapping the name with quotes `"`, or once you get the file, rename it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Change `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]` to `^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\s]`

And, in `[]`, `_` and `.` do not need to be escaped. If `-` is the last char, it does not need to be escaped, too. So `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s.-]` is ok.

Comment: i have replaced the string with your string but doesn't work, i have a file called upload.cgi, maybe it is the solution

Comment: I have modified the file upload.cgi and it works fine, but thanks for the comments and answers :D